# Create Latest Comments View Per Group OG 7.2

Tags: views, organic-groups

Hello it has been a while since i used OG Groups (and Panels) and im struggling a bit to create a view for the group home page showing the latest comments within the group. Its all to do with the Relationships and Contextual Filters. There seems to be so many relationships and filters available to me that its making me struggle a bit.

Could anyone advise me on how to make a view that will display the comments for that group? I think once i see the Relationships used there will be no holding me back from various other things.

Thanks

Comment: ah finally OG membership: OG membership from Node for the relationship and OG membership: OG membership from Node as the contextual filter not forgetting to sort the validation criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OG membership: OG membership from Node for the relationship and OG membership: OG membership from Node as the contextual filter not forgetting to sort the validation criteria